# Java array stack implementation

Tags: java, stack

I have the java code below about stacks. I need help to fill in the methods below where it says `create method` or `create constructor here`.

```
public class ArrayStack
{

    private int[] A;

    private int top;

    public ArrayStack()
    {
        create constructor here
    }

    public ArrayStack(int maxsize)
    {
        create constructor here
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        create method
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        create method
    }

    public int peek()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Peek attempted on empty stack");
        else
            return A[top];
    }

    public void push(int m)
    {
        if(isFull())
            throw new RuntimeException("Push attempted on full stack");
        else
        {
            top++;
            A[top]=m;
        }
    }

    public int pop()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Pop attempted on empty stack");
        else
        {
            int value = A[top];
            top--;
            return value;
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return (top + 1);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String answer = "";
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i <= top; i++)
            answer = "\n" + A[i] + answer;
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code writing request.

Comment: @Jason We'll help with homework, but by the same standards as other questions.

Comment: Why not use [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)?

Comment: I really need help with this homework problem because I am new to java and this stuffs are all new to me.

Answer (score 3):

First, the constructor needs to create the array `A`.

```
private int[] A;
private int top = 0;  // <-- start at 0
public ArrayStack()
{
  this(10);           // <-- delegate to the second constructor.
  // A = new int[10]; // <-- OR 
}

public ArrayStack(int maxsize)
{
  A = new int[maxsize];
}
```

Next, I'll show you how to do one of your other tests. Let's look at `isFull()`, we have `top` that starts at `0` and grows up (see `push()`) - we also have an array `A`. So,

```
public boolean isFull()
{
  return (top >= A.length);
}
```